# Rails config.time_zone and datetime attribute update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my application I have: `config.time_zone = 'Warsaw'`

A strange issue I have, is that it seems like Rails are having problems with comparision of datetime fields.
If I change the datetime 1 hour back (and Warsaw is currently in timezone +0100), Rails won't update the database, even if the field has changed. However, if I change the field once again, then the update will go to the database.

Example:

(Rails 3.1.0, ruby-1.9.2-p290, fresh rails app):

```
$ rails g model User starts_at:datetime
$ rake db:migrate
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > u = User.create({:starts_at => "2011-01-01 10:00"})
SQL (21.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "starts_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 13 Dec 2011 11:32:50 CET +01:00], ["starts_at", Sat, 01 Jan 2011 10:00:00 CET +01:00], ["updated_at", Tue, 13 Dec 2011 11:32:50 CET +01:00]]
 => #<User id: 1, starts_at: "2011-01-01 09:00:00", created_at: "2011-12-13 10:32:50", updated_at: "2011-12-13 10:32:50"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > u.starts_at
 => Sat, 01 Jan 2011 10:00:00 CET +01:00 # datetime created
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > u.starts_at = "2011-01-01 09:00:00" # new datetime with one hour back
 => "2011-01-01 09:00:00" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > u.starts_at
 => Sat, 01 Jan 2011 09:00:00 CET +01:00 # changed datetime
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > u.save 
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > u.starts_at = "2011-01-01 09:00:00"
 => "2011-01-01 09:00:00" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > u.save
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "starts_at" = '2011-01-01 08:00:00.000000', "updated_at" = '2011-12-13 10:33:17.919092' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
 => true
```

I've tested it in this fresh app, because I have a problem with this in larger application. What is going on? I've tried to browse the Rails code, tried to re-copy the relevant code 'by-hand' in console (like update, assign_attributes, even checked time_zone_conversion) and it worked, but not in 'real world'..

Comment: Are you sure that it's not updating the record in the database? I don't see you displaying the value after you save the value the first time. Can you show the output of doing the `u.save` as you show on line 5 of the console, then do a `u.reload`, then do `u.starts_at`?

Comment: I think you'd have better luck if you were using actual instances of Time rather than strings

Comment: they aren't updating, I'm sure. and there's no difference in actual Time instances and created by string. also, strings are needed, because it's also a form issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you stumbled on a similar issue.

The problem appears to be here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb#L62

When rails it testing if the value was changed it compares old & new:

> old = From cache (which is Time in your current timezone)
>
> new = Time in UTC (+00:00) as saved in the database

If the difference in time is the UTC offset, the above erroneously succeeds (luckly the new cached value holds the intended change).

The next save/update compares with the new (and correct) cached value and marks the field as changed.

EDIT:

Done some tests, this works well for me:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb#L50

Change

```
write_attribute(:#{attr_name}, original_time)
```

to

```
write_attribute(:#{attr_name}, time.in_time_zone('UTC').to_s)
```

Boris

Comment: it's not working, and it's not pretty. I think the problem is with the string given to create a new datetime object. it assumes, that it is UTC, so with no timezone given, it's wrongly created. For Time object, it's working well, but DateTime object doesn't have an 'zone' config. how to manage this? the date string is given from a timepicker in the form, and update is using DateTime for datetime field in model

Comment: Why not convert your timepicker result to the local Rail's timezone ? (or filter on the model to convert it into Time.zone object).

DateTime should also be able to preserve time-zone..

Comment: but it does not :/ and it's a bug, but Rails team is silent about this. I will filter it in the model, or some other way, but it's not in one place in the application, so it's starting to be smelly.. **edit**: I didn't notice your edit ;), that should work :)